# NativeBase List not updating

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, reducers, rerender

So I got an object what looks like:

```
[
  {
    title
    data: [
      {
        id
        name
        checked
      } 
    ]
  },
  ... ( * n item)
]
```

These states are in a reducer, so in a store.
When I click on an item, I toggle the checked.

The reducer:

```
switch(action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_ITEM:
        const { row, column } = action.payload
        let newState = state.slice()
        newState[row].data[column].checked = !newState[row].data[column].checked
        console.warn(`the references are: ${newState == state ? 'same' : 'different'}`)
        return newState
```

And the component (the Screen is connected to the store):

```
<List dataArray={list}
                    renderRow={(item, sectionID, row) =>
                        <View>
                            <ListItem itemDivider>
                                <Text>
                                    {item.title}
                                </Text>
                            </ListItem>
                            <List dataArray={item.data}
                                renderRow={(subitem, sectionID, column) =>
                                    <Item
                                        toggled={subitem.checked}
                                        text={subitem.name}
                                        onPress={()=>toggleItem(row, column)}
                                    />
                                }
                            />
                        </View>
export default connect(
    state=>({
        list: state.list
    }), {
        toggleItem
    }
)(ListScreen)
```

When I toggle something, I can see the state is changed in the store, and I can see that the reference is changed too, but yet the List won't trigger the update. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating your state. This is against Redux.
You should return a copy of your state.

```
  const newState = state.map((value, index) => {
    if (index != row) {
      return value
    }

    return {
      ...value,
      data: value.data.map((dataValue, dataIndex) => {
        if (dataIndex != column) {
          return dataValue
        }

        return {
          ...dataValue,
          checked: !dataValue.checked
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

NOTE: NativeBase will return a "string" index value. That's why we are not using `!==`. You might cast the row and column to integer via `parseInt`.